# What problems can an ADSP record in DNS cause for mailflow?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spam, dkim

ADSP is an entry in DNS that works allows a domain owner to assert that all email must be signed with DKIM.  (similar to the `-all` and `~all` in SPF/SenderID).  Messages that fail ADSP policy may be rejected.

Apparently DKIM has a ton of issues with mailing lists.

- What specific mailinglist software has issues with DKIM and therefore ADSP?
- What else has an issue with DKIM and should make one reconsider deploying ADSP?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, [ADSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Author_Domain_Signing_Practices#Author_Domain_Signing_Practices) is simply the mechanism for defining **a** policy. Specifying `dkim=unknown` is equivalent to not specifying an ADSP policy. I'm assuming that you're specifically referring to the `all` and `discardable` policies here.

The problem with mailing lists occur when the message body or any signed headers are modified. This commonly occurs when adding a footer with list information, which is fairly common behaviour by all mailing list software. I think that pretty much all mailing list software will break DKIM signatures.

Unfortunately there is no consensus yet on how to handle DKIM with remailers. There is a wiki page discussing [DKIM in Mailman](http://wiki.list.org/display/DEV/DKIM) which discusses the possible solutions. At this stage I would certainly not use `dkim=discardable` if messages are sent to mailing lists, and would be wary of `dkim=all`.

Comment: I just discovered DMARC. Would that address or help identify concerns?

Comment: @makerofthings7 Interesting, I haven't heard of DMARC before. It doesn't address mailing lists though -- they're mentioned in the FAQ, but the approaches are the same as in that Mailman wiki page.